# Toast doesn't show up when clicking button in other activity than Main

Tags: java, android

I am learning Android and I have build a simple Android app that shows Toasts for starters.

In the main activity I have a button that when I press it it shows a Toast and another button that takes you to another activity. This is the code:

```
package ro.serbab.notes;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
setContentView(R.layout.addnotexml);
            }
            });

            Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);

            button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Serban Android", 
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });



    } 
     }
```

This is the second activity:

```
package ro.serbab.notes;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import ro.serbab.notes.R;
public class addnote extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addnotexml);

    Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Serban 
  Android",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
   }
   }
```

The button from the second activity doesn't show any toast. I keep pressing it and it doesn't work.

Comment: why `setContentView(R.layout.addnotexml);`?

Comment: In the first or second activity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `setContentView(R.layout.addnotexml);` this line from onClick and add

when you want to go 2nd activity onClick the button this code will help you out

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, 2ndActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks it works now I can see the toast on the second activity